# Need to have edit button which changes field to editable; on submit it alters database

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, forms

I made a nice flowchart for you since this is kind of complicated.

Basically, I want to have a list of fields from a column in the database, displayed in a table. They have an EDIT button ext to them, and when you click the edit button you can edit the field. Then you click submit and it alters the table with the new value.

I pretty much know how to do each of the individual things, but I am having trouble combining all these things into one.

Flowchart:

[image]

---

**Code:**

---

**STEP 1:**

```
        <table>
            <th>First Name</th>
           <?php 
            // Collects data from "users" table 

             $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") 
             or die(mysql_error()); 

            // array

             $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 

            // print data

             // Print out the contents of the entry 
             Print "<tr><td>";
             Print "".$info['fname'] . " ";
             Print "</td><td>";
             Print "".$info['lname'] . " "; 
             Print "</td><td>";
             Print "".$info['email'] . " <br>"; 
             Print "</td></tr>";

             // loop for each row in the column

             while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
             { 
             Print "".$info['fname'] . " ";
             Print "</td><td>";
             Print "".$info['lname'] . " "; 
             Print "</td><td>";
             Print "".$info['email'] . " <br>"; 
             Print "</td></tr>";
             } 
              ?>
        </table>
```

**STEPS 2 & 3:** (incomplete or possibly inaccurate as well)

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $variable = "somethinghere";                
            $variable = "somethinghere";                        
            $variable = "somethinghere";                
            $variable = "somethinghere";                
            $variable = "somethinghere";                

            $query = "UPDATE users
                      SET fname='$variable1'
                      WHERE $variable2='$variable3' AND $variable4='$variable5'
              (fname, lname, email) VALUES ('".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['lname']."', '".$_POST['email']."')";

            mysql_query($query);

        }else{
    ?>

    <div class="content">
        <form method="post">
            <div><strong>First Name:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
            <div><input name="fname" type="text" /></div>

            <div><strong>Last Name:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
            <div><input name="lname" type="text" /></div>

            <div><strong>Email:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
            <div><input name="email" type="text" /></div>


            <div><input id="submit-button" value="submit" name="submit" type="submit" /></div>          
        </form>
    <?php }?>
   </div>
```

Comment: alternatively, double-clicking on the box makes it editable...

Comment: So what doesn't work? What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery is the way to change it.

Here's a plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html ; http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: ooohhh it's prettyyyy ... can this be incorporated through the back end?

Comment: also note that the tables are called **dynamically** from the database, so the solution will need to support this.

Comment: also does that allow to save to database? needs to be permanent change to database. **UPDATE** - it appears that on submit it will POST to server. So that's good. I'm not sure however if it supports what we are trying to achieve. Let's continue read but please give some input.

Comment: also note that the tables are called **dynamically** from the database, so the solution will need to support this.

Comment: So far I am loving this solution, although if you could provide an example implementing that code, that would be awesome for me to get started.

Comment: It allows to post, since it's a form, contacting to the webserver. It's enough to catch the posted values and use in the DB. The quote below is from the plugin description: `Normal flow is this. User clicks text on web page. Block of text becomes a form. User edits contents and presses submit button. New text is sent to webserver and saved. Form becomes normal text again.`

Comment: Look at the demo. Open your console and edit a text. You'll see how it contacts: _method put
id paragraph_1
value 1213123
Source
value=1213123&id=paragraph_1&_method=put

Comment: P.S.: All the examples and needs to use it, are in the second link :)

Comment: I need a working example of an UPDATE sql code integrated with it. There is nothing like that on the example page.

Comment: I'm working on it but if someone can post a working example it will help a lot.

Comment: Look at your another topic, I posted an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019345/how-can-i-integrate-jeditable-with-php-and-sql-code/16019896#16019896